# How to install Android SDK and Java Development Kit for Xamarin.Android on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new to android app development and a friend recommended me to use Xamarin. So I went to go check it out and I installed Xamarin + Visual Studio 2017. After that, I went through some tutorials of how to work with it and making your first app. However, I couldn't do that as this happened:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8opiW.jpg)

I don't exactly know what to do from here. I checked many other tutorials but they didn't seem to help. Can anyone here show me how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty much self explanatory, you need to set there three "variables" in Visual Studio options.

Here you can see what my (and default) paths looks like.

[image]

Also best tutorial for Xamarin installation on Windows is Xamarin official one from their documentation, [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/windows/) you can find all info that you need.

If you don't have these folder and files you need to install missing ones.

[Java Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

[Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) (Note: On this page you can download url for Android SDK)

However if you follow the official Xamarin tutorial, from that I provided above I think that you will have everything that you need.